# How can I convert a High Efficiency Image File to AVIF Image?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source, image-processing

I want to get a [HEIF image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) from my Sony camera published to AVIF for the Web and it would appear `ffmpeg` can't recognise the "HEIF Image HEVC Main 10 Profile" file format and show the error:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i milan2023.HIF -c:v libaom-av1 -still-picture 1 milan2023.avif
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x12ce04ca0] moov atom not found
milan2023.HIF: Invalid data found when processing input
```

[Here is a sample image](https://s.natalian.org/2023-04-05/milan2023.HIF).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think this could be on topic as Apple is pretty much the main adopter of the HEIF format and is used heavily on iOS devices.

Comment: Have you tried the *native* [Sony Imaging Edge Application](https://creatorscloud.sony.net/catalog/en-us/ie-desktop/index.html)?

Comment: A bit meta, but would this question get a better answer if example pictures are given?

Comment: Like the linked sample image?

Answer (score 1):

There are two utilities that can convert this file:  [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/formats.html) and [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).  Both are available via MacPorts and Homebrew.  I prefer GraphicsMagick (and switched from IM) because it is faster and smaller than ImageMagick.

The GM command is quite simple:

```
gm convert input.HEIV output.AVIF
```

The IM command is identical except for the`gm` prepending the full command.  It’s simply `convert….`

GM uses a single binary `gm` where as IM has several binaries: `convert`, `identify`, `morgrify`, etc.

Comment: ```❯ gm convert milan2023.HIF milan2023.avif
gm convert: No decode delegate for this image format (milan2023.HIF).

~/Desktop/milan-marathon
❯ mv milan2023.HIF milan2023.HEIV

~/Desktop/milan-marathon
❯ gm convert milan2023.HEIV milan2023.avif
gm convert: No decode delegate for this image format (milan2023.HEIV).
```

Comment: Those are supported formats and I’ve converted HEIV formats previously.  Try converting to png to see if that works.

Comment: ```❯ gm convert milan2023.HIF milan.png
gm convert: No decode delegate for this image format (milan2023.HIF).```